# Is it safe to use non-local variables in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, express

Is it safe to do something like this in Node.js/Express.js?

```
// use Object.create(null) so we don't have to worry about key collisons
// see http://www.devthought.com/2012/01/18/an-object-is-not-a-hash/
var theHash = Object.create(null);

exports.store = function (req, res) {
   key = getUniqueKey();
   theHash[key] = req.param('val');
   // finish the request, &c.
}

exports.retrieve = function (req, res) {
   res.end(theHash[req.param('key')]);
}
```

Basically, I'm building a short-lived short URL service, and this seemed like an easy and fast way to do it. Items are removed from the hash every 24 hours so it can't get to large. Is this safe, or do I need to use a database of some sort?

Comment: Safe as in what? What wouldn't be safe?

Comment: @Layke I want to make sure that I'm not going to lose stored values for scoping or other reasons (other than regular clearing or a server crash). I know that this is safe in Javascript in general, but I'm new to Node.js. I also would like some comments on whether this is poor design.

Comment: also, is it safe from race conditions?

Comment: See http://www.devthought.com/2012/01/18/an-object-is-not-a-hash/

Comment: @DeaDEnD good point. In this case it isn't an issue because getUniqueKey returns a unique key that must contain one letter and one number, but in general that's a very good point. I've edited the post to make the example code better.

Comment: @mattwigway this is not safe by HTTP design. I presume `exports.retrieve` is used with a HTTP `GET /store/retrieve?key=...` which of course will break once the in memory store is destroyed on server reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want tips (as per comments), then yes, this is poor design, but not specifically wrong.

You would be better suited to use Redis for this, an in memory key=>value store. What you have done isn't wrong though, but you rightly notice that it feels "dirty" to keep your keys locally( for several reasons, but crucially if node dies, you lose everything).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the several reasons? I'm guessing threading is one, are there others?

Comment: @mattwigway threading? You don't need to think about threading if you use Node.js. It runs on only one thread! Only other extern things like file/network access are done on other threads.

Comment: I worded that poorly. I assume if a Node app became really popular, one might need to scale by using multiple processes (not multiple threads)

Comment: Yes, that would be another reason. There are just too many little quips which don't make that soution "perfect". Whereas an in memory store would be ideal.